# How can I dynamically map the schema of a pipe delimited text file without header in Spark Scala?

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I am using Spark 2.x version.

I am trying to map schema dynamically after reading content in spark variable from a pipe delimited text file without header in Spark Scala.

Text File Content - File.txt:

```
12345678910|abc|234567
54182124852|def|784964
```

Schema to be mapped:

```
FS1|FS2|FS3
```

Below is the code I tried.
Also I tried the following code from an example from the below link but it is not working.
https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-read-text-file-rdd-dataframe/#dataframe-read-text

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Dataset}

val df = spark.read.text("dbfs:/FileStore/tables/Sample1-1.txt")

import spark.implicits.
val dataRDD = df.map(x => {
val elements = x.getString(0).split("|")
(elements(0),elements(1),elements(2))
}).toDF("FS1","FS2","FS3")
dataRDD.printSchema()
dataRDD.show(false)
```

After executing the above code, I am getting the below output which is not expected,

```
\+---+---+---+
|fs1|fs2|fs3|
\+---+---+---+
|1  |2  |3  |
|5  |4  |1  |
\+---+---+---+
```

I want the New File to be saved as - File1.txt which will contain the file content along with Header

```
FS1|FS2|FS3
12345678910|abc|234567
54182124852|def|784964
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a header to your csv file.

You have a text file and you already know the delimiter which is |

You should write something like this

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

val df = spark.read.option( "delimiter", "|" ).csv("dbfs:/FileStore/tables/Sample1-1.txt")
val columns = Seq("FS1", "FS2", "FS3")
val resultDF = df.toDF(columns :_*)

// If you want your result as one file, you can use coalesce.

resultDF.coalesce(1)
      .write
      .option("header","true")
      .option("delimiter","|")
      .mode("overwrite")
      .csv("output/path")
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure the reason behind saving the file `.txt` file format. Saving it in .txt file format is bit tricky.

If you can write the Dataframe, using .csv format like below

```
dataRDD.write.option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "|").csv("output/")
```

it would be rather easy.